# C++ Interrupted Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge, sorting

I've written an [interrupted bubble sort](https://www.codeeval.com/browse/158/), which prints the intermediate result after some specified number of iterations of bubble sort. But I seem to have an speed issue. Could anyone help me spot some places that need to be optimized or are just plain wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::ifstream;
using std::stoi;
using std::stringstream;

template<typename T>
void printVector(vector<T> vect) {
    for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            cout << vect[i];
        } else {
            cout << " " << vect[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void swap(T &elementOne, T &elementTwo) {
    T temp = elementOne;
    elementOne = elementTwo;
    elementTwo = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(vector<int> numbers, long int iterations) {
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
            if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) {
                swap(numbers[j], numbers[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    printVector(numbers);
}

void parse(string line) {
    size_t delimiterPos = line.find("|");
    long int iterations = stol(line.substr(delimiterPos + 1));
    string numbersString = line.substr(0, delimiterPos - 1);

    stringstream numbersSS(numbersString);
    vector<int> numbers;
    int tempNum;
    while(numbersSS >> tempNum) {
        numbers.push_back(tempNum);
    }
    bubbleSort(numbers, iterations);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ifstream file(argv[1]);
    string line;
    while(getline(file, line)) {
        parse(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A speed issue with bubble sort? That seems hard to believe... :-)

Comment: FeelsBadMan the problem says to use bubble sort :(

Comment: The best way to speed up a bubble sort is to use a better algorithm.

Comment: see also: [Ruby Interrupted Bubble Sort](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/102518/93149).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Single Responsibility**

  As written, `parse` parses data *and* sorts them. This is plain wrong. Same goes for `bubbleSort` which sorts *and* prints. I recommend to change `parse` to

  ```
  long int parse(string line, vector<int>& numbers);
  ```

  and use it as in

  ```
  vector<int> data;
  while (getline(file, line)) {
      long int iterations = parse(line, data);
      bubbleSort(data, iterations);
      printVector(data);
  }
  ```
- Kudos for *not* `using namespace std`!
- The code seems to implement interrupted bubble sort correctly. I don't really understand the expected outcome of the assignment so no comments on the speed.

Answer (score 2):

**printVector**

1. It should take the vector as a reference - there is no need to copy the entire vector just to print it.
2. You should make use of the newer features of the C++ language which were introduced since C++11, like `auto` and range-based for loops.
3. You can remove some conditional statements from the implementation by adjusting the logic slightly.

Overall the refactored function looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void printVector(vector<T> &vect) {
    string separator = "";
    for (auto const &T item : vect) {
        cout << separator << item;
        separator = " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

**swap**

No need to re-invent the wheel. Use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead.

---

**bubbleSort**

1. You pass in the vector by value which means a copy of the original vector is passed in. This means the sort will not be visible outside of the function. So if you were to move `printVector` outside of `bubbleSort` you will see that it prints the unsorted original vector. You either need to pass the vector as a reference or return the sorted copy from the function.
2. `int` is not guaranteed to be able to index all items in a vector. You should [use `vector<T>::size_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7636323/220986) for the index variable.
3. You can avoid the whole indexing by using iterators and [`iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap).

The refactored function looks like this:

```
void bubbleSort(vector<int> &numbers, long int iterations) {
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        auto end = numbers.end() - 1;
        for (auto it = numbers.begin(); it != end; ++it)
        {
            if (*it > *(it + 1)) {
                std::iter_swap(it, it + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Starting each iteration at `numbers.begin()` is not exactly bubble sort.)

Comment: @greybeard: For all I know it is, and [wikipedia agrees too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation).

Comment: Sorry, must have been confused: not stopping one element earlier than in the previous iteration is non-standard, even if the source quoted dubs that "optimized".

Answer (score 1):

#### Out of bounds

```
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
        if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) {
```

When `j` reaches `numbers.size() - 1`, you will read past the end of your vector.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write your own `swap()` function.  You can use [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).